# Prove that following sequence has upper and lower bounds

Tags: calculus

I have to prove that $x_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n$ sequence is bounded. Here's what I've tried:
$x_n=(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$, But can not proceed. I have to find lower and upper bounds of this sequence.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that a convergent sequence must be bounded?

Comment: @jolskey The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". Please visit https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

You are close, multiplying by the conjugate is the good first step

The lower bound of $0$ is obvious. For an upper bound, I assume the indexing starts at $1$. Note that 
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}
$$
Since $\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\geq \sqrt{1+1}+1 $ for $n\geq 1$.

These are actually the least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds, one cannot do better.

Comment: $0<x_n\leq\sqrt{2}-1$ is that the final answer?

Comment: Where are you getting that upper bound from?

Comment: It's the value of $x_1$

Comment: Oh I see, yes you could say that, but do you understand why?

Comment: Well, what I understand is that the sequence gets its maximum value when $n=1$, when n increases then the sequence gets close to $0$. Is that right?

Comment: That sounds good to me, although I didn't show that it was decreasing, only that every term was bounded above by the first term (one could easily show it is decreasing, thought).

Answer (score 1):

For each natural $ n,$

$$n^2 <n^2+1 \le n^2+1+2n$$

or
$$n^2< n^2+1\le (n+1)^2$$
thus

$$n<\sqrt{n^2+1}\le (n+1)$$

or

$$0<x_n\le 1$$
and this means that the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$x_n=\sqrt{n^2+1}-n>\sqrt{n^2}-n=n-n=0$$

as a lower bound. For an upper bound, note that

$$x_n^2=\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)^2=n^2+1-2n\sqrt{n^2+1}+n^2=2n^2+1-2n\sqrt{n^2+1}$$

$$<2n^2+1-2n\sqrt{n^2}=2n^2+1-2n^2=1.$$

Taking the square root of both sides,

$$x_n<\sqrt{1}=1.$$